# Opening Weka .model files with R

Tags: r, interop, weka

Is there anyway to open a Weka model saved as a ".model" file into R in order to use it to make predictions on new data?

**Edit**: The model is constructed using Clus "http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/clus/"

Comment: Yes.   Oh, wait -- you want to know how?  Please post a link to either a `.model` file or to the specification which tells how such a file is constructed.

Comment: Are you aware of [RWeka](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/index.html)?  I have not been able to see a way to load an existing ".model" file, but you may be able to use it to recreate your classifier in R.  Also, this link may provide some insight http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-save-load-RWeka-models-into-from-a-file-td870876.html

Comment: According to other fora, the .model file is a serial binary, so you'll need to dig up the format from either the weka sourceforge page or one of the weka wikis (say **that** three times fast) out there, I fear.

Answer (score 0):

Clus `.model` files are actually different from Weka `.model` files, and therefore, one cannot use Weka model files loaders to open Clus model files.